# Why does SIGSEGV disappear if I print data on the screen?

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault

The core code of a simulation I am writing goes like:

```
for(int it = 0; it < Nt; it++)
{
   //cout << it << endl;
   variables = var_function(variables, it);
}
```

This code gives me SIGSEGV when run. To find out in which time `it` does the forbidden memory access happen I print on the screen with the line `cout << it << endl;`. The weird behavior is that when that line is un-commented, the SIGSEGV error disappears. What is going on?

Comment: Undefined Behaviour is going on. The "undefined" part means that it's perfectly fine to throw an error if there is no print and no error when print is added.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it does in a wide way, but would you know how could I find where exactly the code is leading to this undefined behavior?

Comment: By using an actual debugger. Unfortunately, trace debugging will just not work for C or C++.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am using the one that comes with Dev-C++ (I work on Windows). Any recommendation? Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: @AliEsquembreKucukalic Keep removing code until the error goes away. Then add back the code you removed last. Repeat removing different code until you have a minimal piece of code that reproduces the error. Then share that code with us in a new question.